# How run server and client frames in same app with one jar file

Tags: java, sockets, netbeans, client

I have code to client and server chat, and I need to make this run in jar file but I don't know how to run the server frame and when it runs, the client frame run by itself.

I have tried to make it with threads but not work.

Server Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {             
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new chat_server().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
    String magin ="";
    try {         
      ss=new ServerSocket(444);
      s= ss.accept(); 
      din= new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
      dout= new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

      while(!magin.equals("exit")){   
        magin=din.readUTF();
        msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().trim()+"\n Client:\t"+magin);
      }
```

Client code:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new chat_client().setVisible(true);
        }
    });



    try{             
      s= new Socket("localhost",444); 
      din= new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
      dout= new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
      String magin ="";
      while(!magin.equals("exit")){        
          magin=din.readUTF();
          msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().trim()+"\n Server:\t"+magin);
      }
```